# MySQL ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version

Tags: mysql, privileges

When I tried to grant privileges on users at mySQL, the error happened.Am I type something wrong on the command line?

mySQL Ver 8.0.16 for macos10.14 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL).

```sql
mysql>grant all privileges on librarydb.* to 'phill'@'%' identified by '123456';
```

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'identified by '123456'' at line 1.
```

Comment: try only this much

`grant all privileges on librarydb.* to 'phill'@'%';`

Comment: `identified by` clause is used to define a password during the creation of a user. Get rid of that as @SumitBadaya suggests.

Comment: @SumitBadaya wow, it works! thank you very much! But why I needn't identify by the password in this case?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I got it, thanks for your help!

Comment: alter user librarydb identified by '123456' to change password.

Comment: you're welcome :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version is your MySQL? If it's 5.7 or later, maybe same as this question:

[Unsuccessfully granting privileges](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/210185/unsuccessfully-granting-privileges)

Answer (score 6):

The next command

```
mysql>grant all privileges on librarydb.* to 'phill'@'%' identified by '123456';
```

Should be changed to:

```
mysql> create user 'phill' identified by '123456';
mysql> grant all privileges on librarydb.* to 'phill';
```

if the 'phill' user have not been created yet. If it have been created earlier, then use `alter` instead of `create`